# web-runner for jbehave: is there a way to manage the stories in the web?

Tags: bdd, jbehave, atdd

I'd like to have my pre-existed jbehave stories to be displayed in some web app, and to make it possible for the business people to create and to save the modified stories in the web UI, as well as run it via the web UI.

I have tried the jbehave web-runner (http://jbehave.org/reference/web/preview/customising-web-runner.html), but there is no way to save the tests and to manage the via the web. Is there some solution that makes it possible to

```
 1) manage the hierarchy of jbeahave stories
 2) edit jbehave stories on the manner of FitNesse and save the versioning (via svn)
 3) run the stories and display the run results in the web interface?
```

PS
yes, I believed jbehave web-runner it was created to do such things, but i can't see it properly working: when i start it, i don't see in the web interface the trader.story, existing in code; when I submit the story and run it i get

```
Generating reports view to     'C:\jbehave-web\examples\trader-runner\target\jbehave' 
  using formats '[]' and view properties '{defaultFormats=stats, decorateNonHtml=true,
  viewDirectory=view, decorated=ftl/jbehave-report-decorated.ftl, reports=ftl/jbehave-
  reports-with-totals.ftl, maps=ftl/jbehave-maps.ftl, navigator=ftl/jbehave-navigator.
  ftl, views=ftl/jbehave-views.ftl, nonDecorated=ftl/jbehave-report-non-decorated.ftl}'
  Reports view generated with 0 stories (of which 0 pending) containing 0 scenarios 
  (of which 0 pending)
```

when I go to view story:

```
       http://localhost:8080/trader-runner/story/view?6
```

and try to download the txt output, i get

```
  C:\jbehave-web\examples\trader-runner\target\classes\web-20140213-125844.txt (The
     system cannot find the file specified)
```

so, what the problem to run it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have ran the JBehave-Web app myself recently and I am pretty sure it allows you to add and save new stories.   The user web interface leaves much to be desired, but on a basic level, it is capable of what you say.  See the "trader runner" example.

Comment: yes, I believed it was created to do such things, but i can't see it properly working; i have updated my question to explain the problem; please help!

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  Yes, I can say that I saw the exact same error while trying to use the app but the error didn't prevent me from creating or saving stories.  Your right, the stories wont run from the Wicket app and they can only be ran from IntelliJ.  Now that you edited your question, yes, I can validate that I also had the same errors that you are seeing (running the project on Windows).

Comment: There are multiple versions of JBehave-Web out there.  Which one are you using?  I bet that trying a different version might work and then you can enter a bug when you nail down what the regression actually is.

Comment: I entered the same bug a month ago on their project on GitHub and here is the link:  https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-web/issues/13 .  They chastised me for reporting the bug in that location and ignored my bug report.

Comment: I would send a email to the devlist and refrence the bug I entered above on github.  To: dev@jbehave.codehaus.org  .  I also want to know the solution to this bug.

Comment: great! so, you say that you getting this trouble when running the project on Windows? I'm getting exactly the same error while doing it in Ubuntu. I'm using 3.5.5 and 3.6-beta1 with the similar result; the difference between them is just styling of the web

Comment: One of use should enter it as a official bug and refer back to this stack question in the bug description.